# macアップデートによりmysqlが破損？

Tags: mysql, macos

本日macのアップデートを実行した所、macにインストールしているmysqlのデータベースのテーブルにアクセスできなくなるという現象が発生しました。
（幸い開発テスト用データベースのため被害なし）

データベースは存在しており、　show tables　でそのデータベース内の全てのテーブルも確認できます。
しかし、その全てのテーブルにアクセスしようとすると
ERROR 1146 (42S02): Table 'iantenna.category' doesn't exist
という感じのエラーになります。

また、該当のデータベースを削除しようとしても
ERROR 1010 (HY000): Error dropping database (can't rmdir './iantenna', errno: 66)
とでてエラーになります。

その原因は分かりました。
それは、データベース名の大文字小文字を「判別しなくなっている」ということでした。
例えば、 iAntenna という名前でデータベースを作っていた場合、今回の不具合が発生します。
MySQL上で　iAntenna　を　iantenna　と置き換えているみたいです。
（ただしshow databasesではちゃんとiAntenna表記）

同じ現象の発生した方いらっしゃいますか？
macのアップデートのせいなのかを確認したいです。

私はmacのアップデートを行って再起動した瞬間から発生致しました。

なにか、対策はあるのでしょうか

MySQLバージョン
Server version: 5.6.14 MySQL Community Server (GPL)

今回適用したMacアップデート（１つのみ）
OS X EI Capitan アップデート
10.11.3

Comment: 正常に動くようにしたいのではなく、現象の原因を確認したいのでしょうか？`show variables where variable_name='lower_case_table_names';`で数字は何が出ますか？この値が勝手に変わってしまったということでしょうか？`my.conf`が消えるとか、そういうところでしょうか？ちなみにアップデート前のバージョンなどはお分かりになりますか？

Comment: コメントありがとうございます。
show variables where variable_name='lower_case_table_names';
では　2　が返されました。

my‌​.conf　はタイムスタンプが2015になっていました

アップデート前のバージョンは分からないです…
（一応ですが、SQLはアップデートしていません）

Answer (score 0, accepted):

古いOSのMacが無いので憶測になってしまいますが、
設定が変わったのではなく**設定が使えないようになった**のではないのでしょうか？

`lower_case_table_names=2`はテーブル名をそのまま保持します。
大文字小文字も全てそのままです。
ただ参照しに行く際に全て小文字に置き換えてLookUpします。
要は大文字小文字を無視するわけです。

**ただし**
`大文字小文字を区別しないファイルシステムでのみ`でしか動作しません。
恐らくアップデート前は大文字小文字を区別しなかったのが
アップデートで区別するようになったのではないでしょうか？

大文字小文字を区別したいのであれば`lower_case_table_names=0`にする必要があります。

Comment: ありがとうございます

肝心なことを忘れていました
OS起動と同時に自動起動するようにSQLサーバーが設定されていたのですが
今回は自動起動してくれていませんでした
（手動起動はエラーもなしに起動しましたが）

やはり、設定の読み込めなくなった感じのようです